# Why cannot deploy VS 2013 ASP.NET to existing Virtual Machine at Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, webdeploy, azure-virtual-machine

I have an ASP.NET project initially developed and deployed using Azure Web Sites, without direct access to the machine.

I would like to deploy the same project on an existing Virtual Machine under my account at Azure.

Unfortunately, when try to select the Virtual Machines option here:

[image: No virtual machines appear in the list.]

I get an empty list - although there is a machine under my Azure account.
I get an option to create a new Virtual Machine - but I want to avoid it.

Is it posisble to solve it, by configuring a Web Deploy service on the machine? Some other trick?

Comment: Are you connected to the right Azure subscription? You can have multiple subscriptions per account.

Comment: Stupid question but have you tried logging in and out. I have had that issue some times and that fixes it for me.

Comment: Seems like indeed WebDeploy was missing from the VM I worked with. IIS was configured there but not WebDeploy.